# How remove Polyline from map in GWT Gmaps

Tags: google-maps, gwt, polyline

i using GWT in my project with Gmaps, and i drawing many polylines, but in time I need to force cancell the handler to draw polyline in time of execution, this cancel only when limit of vertex are reached.

Let's see bellow, I've tried many ways, but I can't do this. =/

`LatLng [] inicialize = new LatLng[1];`

```
        // setando numero maximo de pontos e criando a "caneta"
        PolyEditingOptions opcoes = PolyEditingOptions.newInstance(max_cliques);
        pol = new Polyline(inicialize, "#008840", 5, 0.2, PolylineOptions.newInstance());       
        map.addOverlay(pol);
        pol.setDrawingEnabled(opcoes);
```

and to remove I've tried like this ways, but doesn't work

```
        pol.setVisible(false);
        map.removeOverlay(pol);
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

dear if you are using google map v3 , you need to add following line of code to remove

```
pol.setMap(null);
```

and if if you are using google map v2 , you simply add

```
map.removeOverlay(pol);
```